# Proving that linear operator is diagonalizable but not normal

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\mathbb F \in \{\mathbb C, \mathbb R\}$. Define the operator $T_r $ on $\mathbb F^2$ by $T(x)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ r^2  & 1\end{bmatrix}$, where $r\in \mathbb R$. I want to prove that when $0< r < 1$, then $T_r$ is diagonalizable but is neither normal nor self-adjoint.

Of course, if it's not normal, then it's not self-adjoint. But overall I am lost on how to solve this problem. I don't think that applying the spectral theorem will work but could be wrong.

I'd appreciate seeing how this one is done.

Answer (score 2):

To prove it's diagonalisable, find its eigenvalues; they should be distinct.

To prove it's not normal, just multiply it by its transpose both ways
round. You should get two different answers.

Comment: Could you please remind me why multiplying by the transpose  like that is enough to show that it's not normal?

Comment: A real matrix, by **definition**, is normal if it commutes with its transpose.

Comment: I'm actually having trouble computing the eigenvalues. Would you suggest taking the characteristic polynomial?